# Can you take the "other" type of nail clipper in hand baggage?

Tags: usa, airport-security, hand-luggage, prohibited-items

Here are "normal" nail clippers -

[image]

Here's the "other" type of nail clipper

[image]  [image]

{These seem to be called "German" nail clippers, "European" nail clippers, "medical" nail clippers, "professional" nail clippers", or sometimes they are called toenail nail clippers.}

{I've only evert used this "other" type of nail clipper.}

In fact, can you take the "other" type of nail clipper, in carryon baggage on a flight - from the USA say?

I couldn't really find any guidance on this.  (Since the "other" type of nail clipper is not clearly named, it's a bit tricky to google also.)

--

PS I'm fairly sure you're allowed to take the "normal" type nail clipper in hand baggage, even with the TSA/USA.

Comment: The closest items I could find in the [official TSA list](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/all) are pliers (allowed if under 7 inches in total length) and scissors (allowed if blade less than 4 inches).  So I strongly suspect they are allowed.  That page has info on how you can ask TSA directly via Twitter or Facebook Messenger, if you want a definitive answer.

Comment: These clippers are basically the same as [diagonal cutters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_pliers) meant for cutting wire, but I didn't see anything on the TSA list under that name, unless you consider them as included under "pliers".

Comment: ah, that's a great answer @NateEldredge !   I forgot .. as you say scissors ARE allowed, so it makes sense.  (Tiny scissors?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with many items when it comes to hand luggage, they will not be listed in the instruction pages as it's impossible to make a closed-ended list.

Therefore, the security officers will fall back to the *general rules* of sharp items and decide on spot based on their judgement and familiarity with the object.

I can't say I have seen these clippers on-board before, but I think they will be allowed since items that look more "sharp" are already allowed.